# Align horizontally and vertically divs group on page

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, alignment

I've a simple web page which shows current date and time and 4 parameters with names and values in a few div.

Now my attempt looks like this:

```css
.outer {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;
}

#output {
 font-size: larger;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 color: blue;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">Today: current DateTime value</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Parameter 1:</div>
  <div class="inner" id="N">par 1 value</div>
  <div class="inner">Parameter 2:</div>
  <div class="inner" id="V">par 2 value</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Parameter 3:</div>
  <div class="inner" id="D">par 3 value</div>
  <div class="inner">Parameter 4:</div>
  <div class="inner" id="T">par 4 value</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/0bwt6qr8/).

How to align horizontally and vertically this 'table' on page because this page will be shown on big screen (may be TV) ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you somehow

```css
.outer {
  
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    }

.inner {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    flex: 1;
}

#output {
 font-size: larger;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 color: blue;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">Today: current DateTime value</div>
<div class="main-div">
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Parameter 1 sd sdf sdf 34 43 ewr  :</div>
  <div class="inner" id="N">par 1 value</div>
  <div class="inner">Parameter 2:</div>
  <div class="inner" id="V">par 2 value</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Parameter 3:</div>
  <div class="inner" id="D">par 3 value</div>
  <div class="inner">Parameter 4:</div>
  <div class="inner" id="T">par 4 value</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, in https://jsfiddle.net/eoyncd5h/2/ how to make divs with equal width i.e. looks like 'table' ? Because 2 column will have various text length.

Comment: you can give `width: 200px;` to `.inner` div

Comment: What's if length of text will be more than 200px due to font size?